What is the interpretation of this wavy T-SNE plot?
I am trying the T-SNE method to explore high-dimensional datasets and reduce its dimensionality.
And I have ended up with the following plot.
I have used the TSNE parameters n_components=2 and init='pca'.
And the plot uses alpha=0.7.
How would you interpret it?
I can see that the orange dots tend to be more concentrated towards the right of the graph.
But how do you interpret that almost all the dots are aligned and form some kind of wave or sinusoidal?


I'm going to leave my fifty cents here, bearing in mind that this kind of question doesn't have any definitive, "correct" answer. Dimensionality reduction is often used as an exploratory tool, as such, it should be complemented by other analyses and, most importantly, by the context defining your data.
Also, I'm going to examinate the issue with arguments which can be applied either to T-SNE and UMAP, since the two are conceptually similar. I also suggest to run both of them always, in order to check if a pattern emerges repeatedly or not.
Very brief intro to non-linear dimensionality reduction
There are a variety of tools which perform dimensionality reduction with quite similar techniques. Broadly speaking, in a first step these algorithms infer the "structure" of the dataset in the high-dimensional space, based on the distance between couples of points (so yes, the curse of dimensionality can definitely apply in some cases*), and in a second step they try to preserve such "structure" in the low-dimensional layout of the points representing the samples. Quotation marks on the term "structure", since different algorithms focus on different aspects of the dataset. Just to give the idea through a couple of examples, Multidimensional Scaling is designed to (approximately) preserve the mutual distances between points, while UMAP is designed to preserve the topology (things like the presence of holes) of the manifold (in practice: the graph) built in the high-dimensional space.
*On this point, from the documentation of T-SNE:

It is highly recommended to use another dimensionality reduction
method (e.g. PCA for dense data or TruncatedSVD for sparse data) to
reduce the number of dimensions to a reasonable amount (e.g. 50) if
the number of features is very high.

Answer
Beware: this answer is for the interpretation of the specific, single image you are showing, such conclusions are not definitive, yet, as detailed in the other sections.
The fact that the dots form a sort of stripe suggests, essentially, that the data can be more or less ordered by means of a single latent variable. Geometrically, this means that each sample has a similar number of nearest neighbors which, concatenated, form a shape with no self-intersection.
I would not give great importance to the "wavy" layout of the dots, at least on the basis of just one image! If such a pattern emerges consistently, with different choices of parameters and with other algorithms for dimensionality reduction, I would reconsider.
You can greatly benefit from reading sections 5 and 6 of this resource.
As for the clustering, I would say that the orange dots tend to be concentrated towards one end of the manifold, while the blue dots tend to populate the other end. Maybe, a good predictor for the color could be the latent variable defined onto the linear mainfold on which the data apparently live.
Local vs Global properties
In general, the global layout has less importance than the local layout in these kind of algorithms, meaning basically that the information that you infer looking at short distances is reliable, while long distances carry not as much reliable information (for example, on this same line, often it's specficied that the distance between clusters is not informative. See this for more details.). Therefore, the "sinusoidal" shape is much more random than the fact that the dots are sort of linearly connected.
This can be understood from the way the algorithms work: most of them rely on some kind of nearest neighbor graph defined in the high-dimensional space, which by definition ignores everything related to long distances. Here, to me, it's explained quite well for the case of UMAP.
You can take a look to this tool for gaining intuition on the subject. Also, this quote from the documentation of T-SNE:

t-SNE has a cost function that is not convex, i.e. with different
initializations we can get different results.

hints at seeking robust patterns with respect to the choice of the initialization.
Possible complementary analyses
To start, you should play with different values of perplexity.
For UMAP, the main parameter to tune is the number of neighbors.
For investigating the oscillatory relation between points, if you have the suspect of it being meaningful, you could employ UMAP with the cosine distance ('metric' arg), instead of the default euclidean distance. You can specify the same, if you wish, in the low-dimensional plane ('output_metric' arg).
If your data can be organized on a spectrum with two extrema, as it looks like, you could give a try to Self-Organizing Maps (or Kohonen Networks) with a unidimensional lattice. I suggest to do this if you're already used to SOMs, though, since their interpretation is not always straightforward.
Investigation vs Communication
I personally know T-SNE, UMAP and PACMAP (not an exhaustive list). Some help during the investigation could be to run them all on the dataset, in order to check if some patterns emerge all the times, but you should combine this to an intuition of their internal working. This helps you during the investigation, but when you're confident about it, you can communicate the results using the tool which shows the pattern you're confident about the most clearly.
